# Rust STM32: webUSB publishing sensors

Tags: rust, stm32, webusb

For a hobby project using the [stm32f1xx-hal](https://github.com/stm32-rs/stm32f1xx-hal), I'm wanting to periodically read a sensor and then push the values such that I can graph them realtime in a webUSB app.

I have found an example in [webusb_blinky](https://github.com/stm32-rs/stm32-usbd-examples/blob/master/example-stm32f103c8/examples/webusb_blinky.rs) by mvirkkunen which demonstrates the connectivity portion, but it's not clear to me how I would adapt it to publish sensor values. Should I be overriding `control_in`?

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a control transfer that requested the device respond with the current sensor values but the more natural USB mechanism for publishing sensor updates is with an IN endpoint.

The [usbd-serial](https://github.com/mvirkkunen/usbd-serial) module is the best example I can find of creating and using endpoints with this framework. A serial port consists of both an IN and OUT endpoint for bidirectional streaming of data. For your application you would only need the IN endpoint since the device only generates data.

Comment: Thank you for your help, using a combination of your insight and the [webusb-arduino](https://github.com/webusb/arduino) example I was able to figure it out.